# Fling inside Dialog Android

Tags: java, android, dialog, gesture

Can anyone tell me how to get fling motion event inside `CustomDialog` or `Dialog` `Theme` activity. I have tried by `implementing GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` , but it doesn't even recognize touch. Any suggestions ??

```
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // i want to detect this return true; } etc etc..
    }
```

Comment: Please show what have you done.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't set `setOnTouchListener` on your dialog content view. Something like this:

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, mGestureListener);

yourDialogView.setOnTouchListener(new FrameLayout.OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
     }
});
```